# How to create a dummy variable in R by comparing the string values in a column

Tags: r

I am new to R and I want to create a dummy variable in R, which is decided as 1 or 0 depending on the values in one of the column in the dataset.

The values are like "51.1", "47.9","75.4","89.4", etc.

I have to assign 1 to the values which are greater than 55 and 0 to values which are less than 55.
I know this can be done using mutate and ifelse function, however, I am getting stuck as how to compare these string values.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just do `as.integer(as.numeric(df1$yourcolumn)>55)`

Comment: tried using as.integer(as.numeric(df1$yourcolumn)) 
It is giving some random value. For "47.9" it is returning 24, "51.77" to 46.

Comment: It is because your column is `factor` class instead of `character`.  Convert it to `character` before you do `as.numeric` as.numeric(as.character(df1$yourcolumn`

Comment: Hello! Can you tell me if I can use mutate and ifelse for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment leads me to believe that you have a factor variable, so you should therefore first convert to a character vector and then convert to a numeric. The "random values" you are seeing are the integer indices into the factor `levels` attribute:

```
 dfrm$newcol <- as.numeric(as.character(dfrm$oldcol))>55  +0
```

The "+0" is in there to convert logical to numeric. Could also use `as.integer` or `as.numeric` around the whole expression.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with a little bit of adding and changing commands. Thanks to you.

Comment: Hello!
Can you tell me if I can use mutate and ifelse for this purpose?

Comment: You certainly _could_ use those functions. I'm guessing that the reason the  `ifelse` solution offered below by user7537596 failed is that you had a factor and he failed to understand that as the cause of your "random values". The `ifelse` function is likely to be slower because it needs to do more calculations. The `mutate` function is likely to be part of a dplyr or plyr strategy, so if you wanted it used you should post an example that loads the needed packages and constructs an appropriate data object for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example similar to your case:

```
Data <- data.frame(YourCol=c("51.1", "47.9","75.4","89.4", "65.4","56.9","61.4","56.8"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Compare <- ifelse(as.numeric(Data$YourCol) > 55, 1,0)
```

note that by adding "stringsAsFactors=FALSE", it will help you avoid converting your variable into factors or strings. Hence, you will able to convert that variable as numeric and compare their values later.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you, will try this as well.